# Json вывод списка из обьекта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Вывожу с сервера список компаний вида: `{"list":[{"name":"Photolist","location":{"name":"Poland","code":"PL"},"partners":[{"name":"Oloo","value":30},{"name":"Flashset","value":87}]}`

список вывожу

```
$.getJSON('url',
function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data['list'].length; i++) {
        $('.comps-list').append('<li class="listItems"' + data['list'][i].name + '</li>');
    }
});
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии выводились partners , их имена и value но видимо что-то делаю неправильно ибо у partner

```
 $.getJSON('url',
    function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.partners.length; j++) {
                $('.partners').append('<span>' + data.list[i].partners[j].name + '</span>');
                $('.partners').append('<span>' + data.list[i].partners[j].value + '</span>');
          }
        }
    });
```

о видимо что-то делаю неправильно ибо у partners 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' Как вывести правильно партнеров компании?

Comment: Где у вас css использовано? Фактически вам всё равно что в css. Ваш вопрос касается javascript и jquery.

Comment: У вас не задействовано i внутри цикла.

Comment: `data.list.partners` ?

Comment: а что выводит console.log(data) ?

Comment: должна выводить имя и value партнера

Comment: Выложите код на гитхаб

Comment: `j < data.list[i].partners.length` если выше не понятно было

Comment: да спасибо это помогло